# Git branching scheme for ASP.NET MVC project with Areas

Tags: git, asp.net-mvc-4, web-deployment, branching-and-merging, asp.net-mvc-areas

**1. Repository folder structure:**

```
 - repository root
   -- ASP.NET MVC4 Project Folder    
      --- Views & Controllers
          ---- Index, Login, Dashboard, Common styles and scripts
      --- Areas
          ---- Area 1
          ---- Area 2
```

**2. Conditions**

- Given 3 projects (Dashboard, Area 1-2) are being developed almost independently as they are separate tools sharing same database and some of business logic.
- Areas share some of the styles, templates and scripts of the root project
- Release dates of projects are different, every project should be able to be deployed separately keeping others untouched.

**3. Problem**

How to organise git branches scheme to satisfy the conditions

*Necessity of Area usage (instead of separate asp.net mvc projects or simple subfolders in one project) is not a question, we do need it to be this way.*

---

My best idea so far was to have branches organised like this:

```
 - Release    //currently released branch, hotfixes go here
 - Master     //next release candidate
 - Dev        //current aggregated development version
 -- Dashboard  //work on the root project goes here
 -- Area 1     //work on Area 1 goes here
 -- Area 2     //work on Area 2 goes here
```

- Dashboard and areas pull updates from `Master` only.
- Dashboard and areas push updates to `Dev` to test integrated solution.
- Dashboard and areas push updates to `Master` whenever they are proven to be ready for next release.

[image: branch sync scheme]

But there is something incomplete and suspiciously smelling about this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up doing it like this:
[image]

With git's ability to pull/push to/from different remote branches we can keep our current permanent feature branch checked out and sync with remote DEV branch easily.

Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

> - Given 3 projects (Dashboard, Area 1-2) are being developed almost independently as they are separate tools sharing same database and
>     some of business logic.
> - Release dates of projects are different, every project should be able to be deployed separately keeping others untouched.

You've got the answer in your question: those are *three different projects*. Each project should have its own repository. Branching is not meant for this kind of workflow and I'm afraid, using them to manage separate projects in one repo will be a pain.

Create a repo for each of those projects and a fourth repo for your whole application. Add those three projects as [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). This way you'll be able to manage the subprojects separately and also freeze combinations of their states as releases of your larger project.

Comment: Well, submodules are quite a pain themselves, but worth to give it a thought, thanks.